# How to prefetch image in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, image, gwt, prefetch

I tried the following code:

```
RootPanel root = RootPanel.get("root");
root.clear();
final FlowPanel p = new FlowPanel();
root.add(p);
for (int i=0; i<20; ++i) {
    String url = "/thumb/"+i;
    final Image img = new Image(url);
    img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        p.add(img);
    }
});
Image.prefetch(url);
```

But it does not work for me. Did I missed something?

Answer (score 7):

Image load handler is called only in the case, when image is attached to the DOM. So you have to add image to the DOM outside the loadHandler:

```
p.add(img);
img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
        //do some stuff, image is loaded
    }
}
```

Comment: dreak is right, your code has a logic error and the img is never attached to the DOM. Compare your code with this snippet

Answer (score 1):

What Stan said makes sense.

I think the problem is that the LoadHandler isn't being called for some reason.  I've always managed without a LoadHandler, but I usually add an errorHandler as per the JavaDoc demo which is triggered if loading fails.  This should work:

```
final Image img = new Image();

img.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
      public void onError(ErrorEvent event) {
        // Handle the error
      }
    });

img.setUrl(url);
p.add(img);
```

See the example in the GWT Javadoc:  http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageElement img = DOM.createImg().cast();
img.setSrc("images/myImage.png");
```

Comment: How should this help?

Comment: it's a shorter way of accomplishing the prefetch

Comment: But how do I turn the ImageElement into an Image?

Comment: not sure if/how you can convert an ImageElement to an Image

Comment: How do you set the onload handler on the ImageElement?

Comment: @confile looks like this question has the answer you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542266/handler-on-dom-elements-in-gwt